# Importación de módulos en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo dos módulos que estoy trabajando en Python.
En uno de estos módulos (al que podemos llamar el módulo "A", tengo la ejecución de un programa y algunas variables que utilizo para su configuración.

En el otro módulo, que llamaremos "B" tengo una serie de funciones que estoy llamando para alimentar el funcionamiento del programa en "A"

Así que llamo a las funciones desde "B" hacia "A" con un:

```
from B import *
```

Hasta ahí todo bien.
El problema es que estoy implementando una nueva función en "B", pero para construirla necesito una variable que está en "A".

Así que voy a B, e implemento un:

```
from A import "variable"
```

Pues bien, cuando hago esto, el programa deja de reconocerme todas las funciones que viajan de B hacia A y me las arroja con un error, como si no estuvieran creadas:

> signos_vitales()
> NameError: name 'signos_vitales' is not defined

¿Alguien sabe por qué ocurre esto?
¿Es por algún tipo de bucle al importar las tablas una apuntando a la otra?

Por X motivos no puedo subir el código aquí, pero he construido un ejemplo que puede graficar bien el problema:

Al abrir un proyecto y crear dos módulos (A y B)
Se ingresa el siguiente código en A:

```
from B import *
def suma(x, y):
   return x + y
resultado = suma(num_1, num_2)
print(resultado)
```

Luego en B se implementa el siguiente código:

```
num_1 = 2
num_2 = 2
```

Hasta ahí todo funcionará bien, pero si al inicio de B implementamos un `from A import *` dejará de reconocer las variables que estabamos llamando desde B.

Comment: Creo que eso debería ser una importación circular

Comment: Estás teniendo un problema de import circulares. Por lo general, esto ocurre por un mal diseño de módulos. Si en verdad tienes que importar cosas de A en B y viceversa, puede implicar una falta de modularidad y un alto acoplamiento. En fin, te puedo recomendar dos cosas: 1. Unir tus dos módulos en uno solo. 2. Si tienes los módulos programados con clases o funciones, puedes agregar el import dentro del metodo o funcion que ocupe la variable que quieres importar.